# why is the main function in c int and not void?

Tags: c, function

The simplest C program I can imagine is this

```
int main(){
   return 0;
}
```

I don't really understand the purpose of the `return 0;` maybe it has something to do with the exit code which is sometimes see when running commands or files from the CLI.
Why can't I define main as void? I would not have to write `return 0;` in that case.

```
void main(){
    /*code*/
}
```

If i am not mistaken in some programming languages main is defined as void so why not it C? Thanks

Comment: "maybe it has something to do with the exit code which is sometimes see when running commands or files from the CLI.": Yes, that's exactly what it is.

Comment: `void main()` is an obsolete definition, supported for backward compatibility. It is only relevant for code that will never `return` from `main()`, such as embedded code.

Comment: "I would not have to write `return 0;` in that case." You actually don't anyway.  There is a special case for `main`; you have to declare it as returning `int`, but you are allowed to omit the `return` statement, in which case it automatically returns 0.  Personally I don't think it's good style, but it's permitted by the language standard.

Comment: @WeatherVane `void main()` is not an obsolete definition and it uses is/was not limited to code that never returns.  Even C23 has "It (`main()`) shall be defined ... or in some other implementation-defined manner."

Comment: `void main()` is only allowed by Microsoft.  All other (hosted) platforms I know of require `int main()` because that's how an exit status is returned to the environment.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/15168) for (many) more details.